# How to find the First Character starting in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
DECLARE @input   NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Create Procedure   Test'
DECLARE @SearhString NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Procedure'

DECLARE @index    BIGINT = CHARINDEX(@keyword, @input)
```

1- I want to find the length of the next character starting after string Procedure

2- After that I want to check if the **dbo** string exists after that length to the specified location.

Suppose the first character **Test** starting at position 14 after string **Procedure**, so I have to use

```
DECLARE @String varchar(20) = SUBSTRING(@input, 21, 10)

Declare @StringIndex BIGINT = CHARINDEX('dbo.', @String)   

Declare @FirstCharacterIndex BIGINT(This will be the index of the first character)
```

If @String not contains string **dbo** then stuff MySchema before string **Test**.

Please suggest.

**UPDATE**

I have updated my question 22 is the result of @index + @FirstCharacterIndex + 9

@index = 8

@FirstCharacterIndex = 4(3 count for spaces and 4th is for first character)

9 = No. of characters of string **Procedure**

Comment: How did you arrive at this part - `SUBSTRING(@input, 13, 10)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this sql below:

```
DECLARE @input   NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Create Procedure   Test';
DECLARE @input2   NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Create Procedure dbo Test';
DECLARE @SearchString NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Procedure';

DECLARE @index    BIGINT = CHARINDEX(@SearchString, @input);


select @input, @SearchString as searchstring, @index as Index_SearchString , @index +len(@SearchString) as Last_CharacterOfSearchString
, charIndex('Test', @input,@index +len(@SearchString)) as test_Index
, charIndex('dbo', @input,@index +len(@SearchString)) as dbo_Index
, substring(@input, 0, @index +len(@SearchString)) as str1
, substring(@input, @index +len(@SearchString), len(@input)-@index +len(@SearchString)) as str2

Declare @dbo_Index int
Declare @str1 nvarchar(max), @str2 nvarchar(max)
set  @dbo_Index = charIndex('dbo', @input,@index +len(@SearchString))

--select @dbo_Index
if @dbo_Index = 0 
begin
  set @str1 = substring(@input, 0, @index +len(@SearchString))
  set @str2 = substring(@input, @index +len(@SearchString), len(@input)-@index +len(@SearchString))

  select @str1 + ' ' + 'MySchema' + @str2
end

--,charIndex('dbo',@input2, @index +len(@SearchString)) as dbo_Index
```

**Updated:**
objective: Get the "Under Fire" first character index ("U")

```
DECLARE @input2   NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Create Procedure    Under Fire   Test';
DECLARE @SearchString NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Procedure';


--,charIndex('dbo',@input2, @index +len(@SearchString)) as dbo_Index
select substring(@input2,17,25)
, CHARINDEX(@SearchString,@input2,0) + len(@SearchString) as LastIndexOf_Procedure
, CHARINDEX('Test',@input2,0)
,len(@input2)
,substring(@input2, CHARINDEX(@SearchString,@input2,0) + len(@SearchString), CHARINDEX('Test',@input2,0)- (CHARINDEX(@SearchString,@input2,0)+len(@SearchString)))



set @SearchString= Ltrim(rtrim(substring(@input2, CHARINDEX(@SearchString,@input2,0) + len(@SearchString), CHARINDEX('Test',@input2,0)- (CHARINDEX(@SearchString,@input2,0)+len(@SearchString)))))

select @SearchString
select 
@input2
,@SearchString as SearchString
,CHARINDEX(@SearchString,@input2,0) as FirstCharacterIndex
```

Comment: I want to find the index of First Character after Procedure not "Test" as string varies on fly

Comment: i have included the test_index in the select statetment

Comment: before you find the index of First Character after Procedure, you need substring any string between the "Procedure" and the "Test", after you know the string, you can use charIndex to get the first character index